# Is it possible to debug VS2010 .NET 4.0 project in VS2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Sure, i can't open VS2010 solution in VS2008.
I try to attach remote debugger from VS2008 to project of VS2010, but it fails.
Can i attach debugger from VS 2008 to .NET 4.0 application built in VS2010?

Assume i can't install VS2010 on this machine.
Universe existence depends on this question...

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think it's reasonable to expect from VS2008 to have the support necessary for debugging CLR 4.0 processes... Can you possibly use WinDbg or some other debugger?

Comment: @Sasha, thanks for your answer! I think WinDbg is a good case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you need [SOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) to debug managed code with WinDbg. WinDbg is really not intended for debugging managed code, and though it's possible, it's painful. Fix whatever is keeping you from installing VS 2010, or convert your project to target a different version of the Framework.

Comment: if you install the dotnet4.0 sdk on the testmachine you can use the dotnet4.0-sdk-graphical debugger

Comment: Can you install the VS2010 remote debugger on that machine?

Comment: yes but i wanted to learn another option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try to attach a .NET 4 app from VS2008, the process appears in the process list - but it is grayed out. So I think it is not possible - which would be reasonable.